# example of a method is int age; normally below the class?

Tags: java

a method example is int age; below the class? and is the other comments correct?

```
public class human { //just a class? 

    //this is a method?
    int age;
    String name;
    String hairColor;
    String gender;

    public void speaking() { //this is the constructor?
        System.out.println("my name is " + name);
        System.out.println("my age is " + age + " years old");
        System.out.println("my hair color is " + hairColor);
        System.out.println("my gender is " + gender);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) { //main is used to excute   

        human earthHuman = new human();//this is known as a object

        //instances?
        earthHuman.age = (18); 
        earthHuman.name = ("dan");
        earthHuman.hairColor = ("black brownish");
        earthHuman.gender = ("male");
        earthHuman.speaking();
    }
}
```

Comment: int age is a variable, not a method.

Comment: More specifically, it's a field.

Comment: No. `int age;` is **not** a method. That is a [field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/field.html) with package-private (default) permissions.

Comment: read something about parts of the class in google IE: https://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/3488176/The-Components-of-a-Class.htm

Comment: `int age;` is a class variable / member / attribute, `public void speaking()` is a method and you don't have a constructor in your class (at least you haven't writte one yourself).

Comment: These are basics and dont apply to only java. A little research would have answered your questions. https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class human { //Here you declare a class 

    //This is a field with package-private (default) permissions
    //might be also called a variable or a parameter
    int age; 
    String name;
    String hairColor;
    String gender;

    public human() { //This is a constructor

    }

    public void speaking() { //This is a method not a constructor
        System.out.println("my name is " + name);
        System.out.println("my age is " + age + " years old");
        System.out.println("my hair color is " + hairColor);
        System.out.println("my gender is " + gender);
    }

    //Main is the first method to be called when program executes, it is 
    //program's entry point
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        //This is an object better known as an instance
        human earthHuman = new human();

        //These are parametes
        earthHuman.age = (18); 
        earthHuman.name = ("dan");
        earthHuman.hairColor = ("black brownish");
        earthHuman.gender = ("male");

        //Calling method speaking on earthHuman instance
        earthHuman.speaking();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

good question, but it doesnt belongs to stackoverflow from my point of view, anyway, check bellow with a little explanations

```
/*
This is a class called human
 - reg. java naming conventions, should be called "Human" 
*/
public class human { 

   /*
    These bellow are variables / class parameters, which belongs to class human 
     (sometimes called also fields, class variables)
     every instance of the given class will have it 
      (independent on another instances- every instance have its own parameters)

      without accessibility modificator (privare/ public/ protected) its kind of "private-package" ref. to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html
   */
    int age;
    String name;
    String hairColor;
    String gender;

    /*
      This is method, constructors are being called the same as the name of the class is
     - in this case eg. 
             public human()
          or parametrized eg.:
             human(int age, String name, String haircolor, String gender)
             human(int age, String name)
             human(int age, String name, String gender)

       as you can see, constructor does not have any return type, method 'speaking' is having return type 'void' (~'nothing')
    */
    public void speaking() { 
        System.out.println("my name is " + name);
        System.out.println("my age is " + age + " years old");
        System.out.println("my hair color is " + hairColor);
        System.out.println("my gender is " + gender);
    }

     //main method, entry point of program, there execution starts
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
         //more exact is: 'earthHuman is instance of class human', technically yes, its object
        human earthHuman = new human();//this is known as a object

        //block where are you setting parameters
        earthHuman.age = (18); 
        earthHuman.name = ("dan");
        earthHuman.hairColor = ("black brownish");
        earthHuman.gender = ("male");

        //calling the method speaking from class human on instance (object) earthHuman

       /* 
       public void speaking() { 
       System.out.println("my name is " + name);
       System.out.println("my age is " + age + " years old");
       System.out.println("my hair color is " + hairColor);
       System.out.println("my gender is " + gender);
       }

       So you should get (reg. above):
        my name is dan
        my age is 18
        my hair color is black brownish
        my gender is male
       */
        earthHuman.speaking();
    }
}
```